# floating point precision. how to get the widest range of values

Tags: floating-point

I'm digging into the problem of floating point values.
I've seen the excellent page at

https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

and I've read many posts.
I came to a conclusion and I would like to know if this is correct.

There is a trade-off between how much precision you can get and how much big is the integer part of your number.

If decide that I only need 2 decimals of precision the range of the values that I can store and retrieve without errors arrives up to 32767,99 (at least this is from an empirical test with the converter above). Instead if I completely renounce to decimals I can get up to 16777216.
Is it correct to conclude that with two decimals I can have 3276800 unique values, and with no decimals at all I can store up to 16777217 unique values?

It might be rephrased as: given that my interest is storing the widest range of unique values with no errors, and given that I'm bound to using floats, is it correct to say that having no decimals is the way to go?

EDIT: what I wrote about going up to 32767,99 is false, I saw it with more empirical tests. So 32767.2 is stored as 32767.19921875. In practice the question becomes: if I'm bound to using floats and I can't afford these errors, is it correct that with no decimals I can correctly represent values from 0 to 16777216?

Comment: Do you want 2 decimals of relative precision or absolute precision? In the latter case, why are you bound to use floats? Fixpoint would be a much better choice in that case.

Comment: I'm happy with having the widest range of numbers, I need to find the scale that lets me have it. If I remove decimals I can have 5 times the values I would have with two decimals. I'm bound to floats because the 3d engine I use works like that.

Comment: I don't think I understand your problem. If you are bound to use [IEEE754 single precision floats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats), then you will have a relative precision of 24bits (which corresponds to slightly more than 7 decimals), and your total range is roughly +/-3.4*10^38. You probably have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: What I saw is that if I use floats as if they were integers I have a range of possible values that goes from 0 to 16777216. No errors, no rounding, it's the exact value. If I use decimals I always end of with some kind of error, that means I don't have as many unique values as using floats without decimals. If I store a number with a decimal more or less I will always end up with some error, so 62798.2 is actually stored as 62798.19921875. By the way I edited the original post because I get errors also with values below 32767,99

Comment: The problem is not stated completely. First, if you want to convert numbers with two decimal digits to IEEE-754 32-bit binary floating-point (“binary32”) with “no errors,” then it is impossible. There is no way to represent .01 in binary32. Any conversion will have an error. Second, if you want to convert decimal numbers with two digits after the decimal point to binary32 and then convert back to decimal numbers with two digits after the decimal point, the first number for which that round trip does not restore the original number is 131072.01.

Comment: In other words, for all numbers with two digits after the decimal point from 0.00 to 131072.00, the original number is recoverable from a binary32 using just straightforward conversions. However, arithmetic on such binary32 generally will not produce the same results as arithmetic on the decimal numbers. Floating-point is not designed to “store” decimal numbers, and you should avoid using it this way.

Comment: If that answers your question, binary32 can exactly represent every integer between -2^24 and +2^24 (and every even integer up to +/- 2^25, every multiple of 4 up to +/-2^26, and so on). I still think you have an XY-problem.

Comment: @EricPostpischil ok that's a precious info. However that means one thing, that I can safely "manage" numbers from 0.00 to 131072.00 which is... 13,107,201 numbers. If I discard any decimal I have from 0 to 16777216 of retrievable values, which is 3 millions more. This is not 5 times as I, incorrectly, calculated before, but still a bit more. The maths that I would perform with those numbers is a concern of course, but first and foremost I wanted to make sure that since I have to use floats as my variables I can retrieve the number that I stored, not something else.